# generate a pdf with input fields editable in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, html2pdf

I have this code on javascript and angularjs to create an editable pdf whereby on the textfields the user may/can input data on the text-fields. The pdf documents download but the textfields are not edittable. Here is the snippet

```
var opt = {
                          margin:       0,
                          filename:     name+'doc.pdf',
                          html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
                          jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
                          pagesplit: true

                        };
                    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
```

upon searching online I saw a related snippet that may achieve what am trying to do but its written in the php and do not know how to convert it to javascript/angular and test the snippet

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4', 'en', false, 'ISO-8859-15');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $html2pdf->Output('pdf_demo.pdf');
```

here is the library I am using

```
<script src="/static/pdf/html2pdf.bundle.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

Please how create a pdf with textfields edittable

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using [this library](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) (it would have helped a lot if you had mentioned that).  As far as I can tell from the documentation, that library converts the HTML to an image, and then turns the image into a PDF. So, it's not possible for the resulting PDF to be fillable.

You may need to do this server-side with a library based on [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which appears to support generating fillable PDFs. Or, you may be able to directly create the PDF (i.e. skip the HTML) with [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

Comment: How can I skip the html with jsPDF or fillable pdf with wkhtmltopdf snippets

Comment: Read the documentation